Removing diamond-like empty shapes from Leaflet (base)maps
Dears,
I am trying to find why I have the diamond-like empty spaces in my leaflet basemaps. Does anybody knows how to get rid of them? I am adding the screenshot here.
I was trying also to set setMaxBounds method but that did not help.
Thank you for your support!


You must have somewhere a CSS style that applies a border radius to the tiles.

Hello Thomas, thanks so much for the comment that helped me a lot! Indeed, I have onAdd method in js creating img element which has border-radius in css, so when I have set it to 0px the issue has gone.
